# Python installing modules : Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopy

I am trying to install Geopy, i am getting following error.
[image]

Till yesterday i have installed packages , there was no probelm.

Thanks
Pavan Kumar

Comment: looks like a mixup between python 2 & 3. Look at `cStringIO`, your anaconda is python 2. `yield from` is a new 3.something feature.

Comment: @pavan kumar better use conda prompt dialog box and type the command as 'conda install -c conda-forge geopy'

Answer (score 1):

The Anaconda you have installed has probably changed pip's default location. Now, pip will mostly be present under anaconda folder in your windows.

type 
'where pip'
in your terminal

now use the pip path and type following in your terminal
'pip-path install geopy'

Hope it helps